# Porting RSVP.js map idiom over to bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, rsvp.js

In [RSVP.js](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js#arrays-of-promises), there is a very elegant idiom:

```
var promises = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13].map(function(id){
  return getJSON("/post/" + id + ".json");
});

RSVP.all(promises).then(function(posts) {
  // posts contains an array of results for the given promises
}).catch(function(reason){
  // if any of the promises fails.
});
```

However I am using a library that already relies on, and exposes some of [bluebird's api](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird). So I'd rather avoid mixing in RSVP.js even if it may seem at times more elegant.

What would be the equivalent in [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#mapfunction-mapper--object-options---promise), of the RSVP.js code snippet above?

Comment: It will be the same `Promise.all(promises).then(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for using Bluebird's `Promise` namespace instead of `RSVP`, everything can stay the same - using [`Promise.all`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise). Also, mixing promises that conform to the [Promises A+ specification](http://promisesaplus.com/) should work well, so you might not even *have* to change anything.

While I personally don't like it much, Bluebird also has its own idiom for this task - [`Promise.map`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#mapfunction-mapper--object-options---promise):

```
Promise.map([2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13], function(id){
  return getJSON("/post/" + id + ".json");
}).then(function(posts) {
  // posts contains an array of results for the given promises
}).catch(function(reason){
  // if any of the promises fails.
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys, my real code that resembles the above works now, using `Promise.all` (and a regular non-Promises map) indeed. I just got lost before with the detail of the `bluebird` example for map (where it promisifies an existing library and stuff in addition to the `.all`. 

Thanks :)